# How to dynamically change images on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem:** The previously loaded images have to be changed dynamically when a new image is downloaded and detected by `image.onload` event. Say, `picture1.png` downloaded and immediately changed, `picture2.png` downloaded and immediately changed and so on. I have tried it as below, but it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 loadImage = function(){    
     var imgs = new Array();    
     var IMG = document.getElementsByTagName('img');    
     for(var i=1;i<=IMG.length;i++)
     {
       imgs[i] = new Image();
       imgs[i].src = "picture" + i + ".png";
       imgs[i].onload = function(){
         alert('picture'+i+' loaded');
         IMG[i].setAttribute('src',imgs[i].getAttribute('src'));
       }           
     }              
 }    
</script>    
 <img src="sample.png" />
 <img src="sample.png" />
 <img src="sample.png" />
 <img src="sample.png" />
 <input type="button" value="Load Image" onclick="loadImage()">
```

How things will happen in the desired manner?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [JavaScript Closure inside loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Note: though not an error, the img tag does not have a closing slash, and browsers are instructed  to ignore it.

Comment: `..... for(let i=1; ....`

Comment: I think it is not cross platform solution @GeoffreyMureithi

Answer (score 0):

Because variables declared with the `var` keyword is function scoped and the `onload` function executes after the loop has finished variable `i` will not equal the value of `i` in that iteration when executing.

Replace your `onload` function with this code instead. It will create a new function scope.

```
imgs[i].onload = function(index) {
  return function(index) {
    alert('picture' + index + ' loaded');
    IMG[index].setAttribute('src', imgs[index].getAttribute('src'));
  }
}(i)
```

I would also change you're code to not loading the image twice.

```
function loadImage() {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = "http://dummyimage.com/150/000/fff&text=Image" + i;
    newImg.onload = function(index, newImg) {
      return function() {
        var img = images[index];
        img.parentNode.replaceChild(newImg, img);
      }
    }(i, newImg)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to change the placeholder images as soon as the new images are completely loaded. By just passing the `src` attribute you rely on caching but the method below, although untested, should do the replacing in place. The `i` is kind of like a pointer which holds the growing value, so you can't use it as a reference in event callbacks.

```js
function loadImage() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = "picture" + i + ".png";
    newImg.onload = function(img) { // Construct a callback for this <img>
      return function() {
        img.parentNode.replaceChild(newImg, img);
      }
    }(imgs[i]);
  }
}
```

**Edit**: as said, I previously introduced another scoping issue in my code when fixing the original one. This is now fixed with a callback constructor function.

Comment: This will only change the last picture and its because of function scope.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/2792083) answer,

> Well, the problem is that the variable i, within each of your
>   anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the
>   function.
>
> What you want to do is bind the variable within each function to a
>   separate, unchanging value outside of the function:

So your code should look somewhat like this :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  
     var IMG = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
     var imgs = new Array(); 
 loadImage = function(){          
     for(var i=0;i<IMG.length;i++)
     {
       imgs[i] = new Image();
       imgs[i].src = "http://dummyimage.com/150/000/fff&text=Image"+i;
       imgs[i].onload = onloaded(i);
     }              
 } 
 
function onloaded(i) {
   IMG[i].setAttribute('src',imgs[i].getAttribute('src')); 
}
  
</script>    
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150" />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150" />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150" />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150" />
 <input type="button" value="Load Image" onclick="loadImage()">
```

Note : array index of `IMG` starts with `0`